# Finding Galois group over Rationals

Tags: permutations, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

I need some help in determining thr Galois group of the splitting field of the polynomial $x^4-2x^3+2x^2+2x+1$. Can I use Sage or Gap for this purpose and how? I am not able to figure this one out.

Comment: Whatever the group is, it had better not have a threefold symmetry element.  The resolvent cubic will have a rational root, which kills such a symmetry.

Comment: A "lucky" observation is that the polynomial is
$$
(x^2-x)^2+(x+1)^2=(x^2-x+i(x+1))(x^2-x-i(x+1)).
$$
The two factors have discriminants $\pm 6i$. We have $\sqrt{6i}=\pm\sqrt3(1+i)$, so the splitting field is $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt3,i)$.

Comment: I did use Mathematica to find the zeros, and to play with the quadratic factors. Another pairing lead to
$$f(x)=(x^2-x+2)^2-3(x-1)^2,$$ allowing a factorization over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt3)$.

Comment: I think I have found an answer: 1) Discriminant of the polynomial is 2304, which is a square; 2) Cubic Resolvent is $x^3-2x^2-8x-8$ which is irreducible over rationals; 3) This gives us the Galois group isomorphism with the Alternating four group.  Used https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/cubicquartic.pdf

Comment: @GregoryE The resolvent is $x^3 - 2x^2 - 8x$. It is definitely reducible. See my answer below.

Comment: Thank you. I got it now! Stupid mistake....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Keith's notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/cubicquartic.pdf) to determine the Galois group of any quartic without explicitly computing the roots.

First you can compute the resolvent of the cubic polynomial, which is $x^3 - 2x^2 - 8x$ and it is obviously reducible. Afterwards you can compute the discriminant. It is a bit more tedious process, but after using formulas in the article you should be able to conclude that it is $2304 = 48^2$, so it is a square. Finally using the notes, if $f$ has reducible cubic resolvent and a square discriminant it must have $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ as a Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$.